# PHP regular expression to parse a CSV line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Using: PHP 7

I need to parse a string from a CSV file and return the values in an array. I'm using preg_match_all, but have had no luck so far.

This is the string:

```
"494","1","41","2009-05-18","NULL","0","3","JONES,ZACK ZX",""
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
 $s = '"494","1","41","2009-05-18","NULL","0","3","JONES,ZACK ZX",""' ;

 $p =  '(?<=^|,)(?:[^,"]+|")?(?=,|$)|(?<=^|,)".*?"(?=,|$)';

 $m = Array();

 $e = preg_match_all($p, $s, $m);
```

After it is executed, the `$m` array should contain all the string values, without the double-quote string enclosure character.

Would appreciate any help in getting the correct regular expression to use.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a regular expression for this, rather than something like [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)?

Comment: @iainn I tried str_getcsv, it did not produce the correct result.

Comment: Regex is not the tool for this. There's no reason why the built-in CSV parsing features of PHP would produce unintended results on a dataset as simple as the one you've provided. Trying to re-create a CSV parser in regex (especially to include all edge cases and escape sequences) is like re-inventing a perfectly good wheel.

Comment: @iainn I gave str_getcsv another try and it worked! I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Following iainn's suggestion, I tried `str_getcsv`, and it worked!

Here is the answer:

```
$m = str_getcsv($s, ",", "\"");
```